# How to go to EndOfFile of a data file while reading it in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a data file which I am reading into Mathematica. Now, the problem is that an important information in the data file is mentioned at the end of the file. I need to read the last line first using Mathematica. The no of lines are different for different data files, otherwise I would have used Skip command to reach the final line.
Could you please let me know if there is a command/routine to do that?
Thanks.
dbm368

Comment: Most active Mathematica answerers have moved to the dedicated site Mathematica.stackexchange.com. You'll probably have better luck there.

Comment: You can use Skip or SetStreamPosition, but only if all the lines have the same length

Answer (score 3):

If you know the length of the last line, you could do:

```
str = StringToStream["abcdefg \n123456"]
eof = SetStreamPosition[str, Infinity]
SetStreamPosition[str, eof - 6]
Read[str, String]
(*
->
InputStream[String, 43]
15
9
123456
*)
```